# BIM 360 Field classic authentication - Single Sign On

Tags: field, autodesk, autodesk-bim360

My company is currently using a username and password to authenticate against the BIM 360 Field classic  [API](https://bim360field.autodesk.com/apidoc/index.html#mobile_api_method_1) . The username is in the format username@corpxyz.com.

We're looking at using Autodesk's  [SSO solution](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/ENU/SSOGUIDE-Okta-Guide/files/SSOGUIDE-Okta-Guide-About-Single-Sign-on-SSO-html-html.html)  so that anyone with an @corpxyz.com email address will use SSO.

Does anyone know if the Field classic API supports SSO? I'm suspecting that once we enable SSO for corpxyz.com login attempts to the API will fail.

**Update (2020-03-17)**

My company is not currently fully enabled for SSO within the domain. We're whitelisting users during our pilot testing. I've found that I can succesfully communicate with the Field Classic API with an SSO enabled account. What still needs to be determined is if this behaviour changes once a domain is fully SSO enabled.

Mike

Comment: Not sure how you whitelisted user accounts, but are you testing with `POST /api/login_by_forge_token` to exchange Forge access token with Field API ticket?

Comment: I'm not familiar with /api/login_by_forge_token. I'm using POST /api/login using username and password to retrieve a Field API ticket. Is there documentation on using a forge token to retrieve a Field API ticket?

Comment: The `POST /api/login_by_forge_token` is the one you're looking for. See my reply below for the instruction. Next time, please ask on the [BIM360 API forum](https://forums.autodesk.com/t5/bim-360-api-forum/bd-p/115) instead since Class Field is not a part of Forge platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use SSO with BIM360 Classic Field, you need to create a Forge developer account, and follow the steps below you should be able to log in with Autodesk ID and by extension SSO:

1. Follow the steps in from this [tutorial](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/tutorials/get-3-legged-token/) and get a forge access token
2. After getting the access token, you can call `POST api/login_by_forge_token` and get a Field internal ticket. Here is the API documentation, but it's not listed on Field API documentation currently since it's for our enterprise customers only.

```
POST api/login_by_forge_token
Description: Attempts to authenticate with the mobile API using a forge access token. On success, returns a 36 byte GUID "ticket" which needs to be passed in on subsequent calls.
 
Status Codes:
200 User has authenticated and is successfully logged in.
500 failed to verify user
 
Access: FREE
Return: JSON - Returns a ticket which must be passed for each subsequent request in the session.
Parameters:
forge_token : string - The forge access token.
device_type : string - (optional) The type of device
device_identifier : string - (optional) A unique identifier for the device.
```

Note1. Please select BIM360 product while creating a Forge app by following the create app tutorial mentioned in the [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/tutorials/get-3-legged-token/).

Note2. This Field internal ticket is the same ticket as when you get it by calling `POST api/login`, and can invalidate it via `POST api/logout`.

Comment: Does this (or another API endpoint) support 2 legged authentication? I tried your solution out and was able to download information from the BIM 360 API. However, since the 3 legged authentication is tied to my account I could only see projects assigned to my account. 

We currently access the Classic Field API using a single service account which has access to all projects using an ELT process. We want to continue using ELT but if this require 3 legged authentication this become much more difficult to achieve.

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't 2-legged access token at this moment, unfortunately. So, we have a wishlist item for this request, `CS-40243` for our engineering team to evaluate the possibility. So, would advise you to create a Field user account for that purpose instead.